# Validate with three xml schemas as one combined schema in lxml?

Tags: python, xml, xsd, lxml

I am generating an XML document for which different XSDs have been provided for different parts (which is to say, definitions for some elements are in certain files, definitions for others are in others).

The XSD files do not refer to each other. The schemas are:

1. http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v2-1/schema/Egov_ch-v2-0.xsd
2. http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-1/schema/forms/FormSubmission-v1-1.xsd
3. http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-1/schema/forms/CompanyIncorporation-v1-2.xsd

Is there a way to validate the document against all of the schemas using lxml?

The solution here is **not** simply to validate individually against each schema, because the problem I am having is that validation fails because of elements not specified in the XSD. For example, when validating against `http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v2-1/schema/Egov_ch-v2-0.xsd`, I get the error:

```
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3006, in lxml.etree._Validator.assertValid (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:125415)
DocumentInvalid: Element '{http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk}CompanyIncorporation': No matching global element declaration available, but demanded by the strict wildcard., line 9
```

Because the document in question contains a `{http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk}CompanyIncorporation` element, which is not specified in the XSD being validated against, but in one of the other XSD files.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to validate *parts* of the XML document against *different* schemas, rather than *all* schemas against the *same* document?

Comment: I'm sure that I would like to check that the combined document is valid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you should only be validating against `Egov_ch-v2-0.xsd`, which appears to define an envelope document. (This is the document you are creating, right? You haven't showed your XML.)

This schema uses `<xs:any namespace="##any" minOccurs="0"/>` to define body contents of the envelope. However, `xsd:any` does *not* mean "ignore all contents." Rather it means "accept anything here." Whether to validate or ignore the contents is controlled by the `processContents` attribute, which defaults to `strict`. This means that any elements discovered here *must* validate against types available to the schema.  However, `Egov_ch-v2-0.xsd` does not import `CompanyIncorporation-v1-2.xsd`, so it doesn't know about the `CompanyIncorporation` element, so the document does not validate.

You need to add `xsd:import` elements to your main schema (`Egov_ch-v2-0.xsd`) to import all other schemas that may be used in the document.  You can either do this in the xsd file itself, or you can add the elements programmatically after parsing:

```
xsd = lxml.etree.parse('http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v2-1/schema/Egov_ch-v2-0.xsd')
newimport = lxml.etree.Element('{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}import',
    namespace="http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk",
    schemaLocation="http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-1/schema/forms/CompanyIncorporation-v1-2.xsd")
xsd.getroot().append(newimport)

validator = lxml.etree.XMLSchema(xsd)
```

You can even do this in a generic way with a function that takes a list of schema paths and returns a list of `xsd:import` statements with `namespace` and `schemaLocation` set by parsing `targetNamespace`.

(As an aside, you should probably download these schema documents and reference them with filesystem paths rather than load them over the network.)

Comment: Thanks for this. What prompted the question is that this simply does not work, because the validator returns a verdict of invalid when it encounters an element not specified within the XSD document it is generated from. I need some kind of way to create a combined validator, aware of the information in all three of the XSD files. I realise that the details of that problem were not in my original question.

Comment: Then the document is invalid for that schema. What makes you think it *should* be valid? XSDs and XML documents cannot be arbitrarily composed together.

Comment: What makes me think that it should be valid is that the element being complained about appears as the content of an element the content of which is specified as `<xs:any namespace="##any" minOccurs="0"/>`.

Comment: See updated answer. You need to add `xsd:import` statements to your primary schema.

Comment: Nice! Thanks! Here is also explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38910347/how-do-i-validate-against-multiple-xsd-schemas-using-lxml